# CSS - select element without text inside

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there any way to select some element that have no text inside?

What it mean:

Lets say we've got such elements

```
<div class="to-select"></div> <-- this is empty
<div class="to-select"><span></span></div> <-- this is not empty, but dont have text
```

Both of them dont have text, however only one of them is empty and can be selected with `:empty`. I want both of them to be selected as they dont have text.

Also, some elements might have only white-space text that came from tabbed html markup etc.

I know it's quite easy to do with js. But I'm looking for css solution if it's possible. I dont like to use js for this kind of problems.

Comment: Not without the help of javascript.

Comment: what do you really need to achieve ?

Comment: Indeed a use-case would be helpful.

Comment: Use case is to style all elements inside another element that dont have rendered text.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, there isn't a selector for elements with no text node children (or descendants).

In Selectors level 4 it may be possible with

```
.to-select:not(:has(:not(:empty)))
```

or, [to account for inter-element whitespace](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-4/#the-blank-pseudo),

```
.to-select:not(:has(:not(:blank)))
```

but since `:has()` may not be fully available in the fast profile, you may not be able to use it in CSS even once Selectors level 4 is implemented.

Using JS is your best bet, unfortunately. The above selector with `:empty` will work in jQuery today, but even once `:has()` is implemented natively, for this specific use case you'd only be able to use it in `document.querySelectorAll()` at best.

Comment: [`:blank` apparently only applies to input elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:blank).

Answer (score 4):

You may try this in your CSS:

```
.to-select:empty {
    <<your attributes>>   
}

.to-select *:empty {
    <<your attributes>>    
}
```

Comment: i guess the main problem is that a white-space or code indent does not match with the :empty selector :)

Comment: Yes, correct. For that JS is the only solution it seems.

Comment: I never think about this selector. Shame for the whitespace, but I guess you could clean up any whitespace using JS and then let CSS handle the rest. I like this solution.

Comment: It don't let me select parent element that have empty children only.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
$(".to-select").filter(function(){
    return ($(this).text().trim() == "")
})
```

Comment: Yes. I know it's easy to do with js.